# Why is my Laravel Export returning a blank sheet?

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I am using Laravel Export to export an excel file of some data. When I create my query, and use `dd()` to check what the data look like, everything looks good. For example:

```
dd($result);

array:510 [▼
    0 => array:24 [▼
        "abc" => "123"
        "foo" => "bar"
        "key" => "value"
        ...
        "pivot" => array:4 [ …4]
    1 => array:24 [▼
        ...
 ]
```

This is what my export method looks like:

```
Excel::create('my-file', function ($excel) use ($result) {
    $excel->sheet('Page1', function ($sheet) use ($result) {
        $sheet->fromArray(array($result));
    });
})->export('xlsx');
```

The above generates a completely blank excel file.

I am not sure how else to troubleshoot this. It seems I am passing in good data, but getting an empty sheet back.

Grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: i think it is good to get data in object format by using get() instead array format?and try this  fromArray($result) works for get method..

Comment: Do you have same key name for each index? and try to dd before passing value to $sheet->fromArray()

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Excel::create('my-file', function ($excel) {
    $excel->sheet('Page1', function ($sheet) {
        $sheet->fromArray($result);
    });
})->export('xlsx');
```

Reffer this link as well - `http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export`
for `Creating a sheet from an array`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$sheet->fromArray((array)$result);
```